# Working with dataframe that uses ':' and 'x' as separators/identifiers within only one columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that provides all kinds of sales info- date, session, time, day of week, product type, total sales, etc.  It also includes a single column that provides the order in which all products were purchased in that session.  Some of the products are text names, some are numbers.

The products with text names never change, but the products with numerical names rotate as new ones are developed.  (This is why they are listed in a single column- the "numerical" products change so much that the dataframe would get maddeningly wide in just a few months, plus some other issues)

Here's a small subset:

```
Session  TotSales    GameList
20764      15        ProductA
31976       7        ProductB:ProductB:ProductB
27966      25        1069x2
324         3        1067x1
6943       28        1071x1:1064x1:1038x2:1034x1:ProductE
14899      12        1062x2
25756       8        ProductC:ProductC:ProductB
27279       6        ProductD:ProductD:ProductD:PcoductC
31981       4        1067x1
2782      529        1046x2:1046x2:1046x1:1046x1:1046x1:1046x4
```

Okay, so in the above example, in session 20764 (the first one), sales were $15 and it was all spent on ProductA.  In the next session, ProductB was purchased three times.  In the third session, product 1069 was purchased twice, and so on.

I am going to be doing a lot with this, but I don't know how to tell R that, in this column, a '**:**' acts as a separator between products, and an '**x**' signifies the number of "numerical' products that were purchased.  Any ideas?

Some examples of what I am trying to know:
1. Which Product was purchased *first* in a session;
2. Which products were purchased most often with each other; and,
3. I'd like to be able to, say, aggregate sessions that contain certain combinations of products (e.g, 1067 and 1046 and Quinto)

I know this is a broad request for on here, but any info on how to get R to recognize these unique-to-this-column identifiers would be tremendously helpful.  Thanks in advance.

Also, here's the dput()

```
structure(list(Session = c(20764L, 31976L, 27966L, 324L, 6943L, 
14899L, 25756L, 27279L, 31981L, 2782L), TotSales = c(5, 5, 20, 
1, 25, 2, 9, 5, 1, 520), GameList = structure(c(6L, 9L, 4L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1046x2:1046x2:1046x1:1046x1:1046x1:1046x4", 
"1062x2", "1067x1", "1069x2", "1071x1:1064x1:1038x2:1034x1:ProductE", 
"ProductA", "ProductD:ProductD:ProductD:ProductC", "ProductB:ProductB:ProductC", 
"ProductB:ProductB:ProductB"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Session", 
"TotSales", "GameList"), row.names = c(320780L, 296529L, 98969L, 
47065L, 19065L, 92026L, 327431L, 291843L, 296534L, 15055L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your reason for this data format "(This is why ...)" is not convincing. Just make it a long-format data.frame and add a column with the number of purchased items and possibly a sorting index. E.g., the `6943` row should become 5 rows since 5 different products were purchased. If you bring your data into this format (which is kind of most common in R) it would be easy to work with it.

Comment: Well, there are apparently a few reasons why it cannot be done that way (which I would prefer, but I'm just the lowly analyst, not the developer).   

One, the way it is stored in the database- as in, it isn't.  This comes from a session file that is restored for the sole purpose of generating this output.  Once the "numerical" games are replaced, they are no longer in the restored sessions, so they cannot be pulled.  The man hours required to continually update the product numbers that need pulled would be prohibitive (i.e hundreds of different product numbers per month).

Comment: Also, due to the size and frequency of these files, I am writing most of the script to run and generate reports automatically- I don't have the time to continually edit the script to reflect the constant addition of new column names.

Comment: Additionally, these sessions are subtotaled for a reason- when they were in long format (which is how they are originally on the datbase, I guess), a single week's worth of data was 150GB...which quickly gets much too large for us to work with.

The current format is done to deal with space and power restrictions.

Comment: Use backticks to refer to columns with special names, e.g. `x$\`special:name\``

Comment: @Andrie It isn't the actual column name with the special character, it is how the values within the column are structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternate with `data.table`.  I won't answer all your questions, but this should get you going.  First, convert to long format:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)    # assumes your data is in `df`
split_fun <- function(x) {
  y <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ":"))
  z <- strsplit(y, "(?<=[0-9])+x(?=[0-9]+$)", perl=T)
  unlist(lapply(z, function(x) if(length(x) == 2) rep(x[[1]], x[[2]]) else x[[1]]))
}
dt.long <- dt[, list(TotSales, split_fun(GameList)), by=Session]
```

Now, to answer Q1 (first product in session):

```
dt.long[, head(V2, 1L), by=Session]
```

Produces:

```
    Session       V1
 1:   20764 ProductA
 2:   31976 ProductB
 3:   27966     1069
 4:     324     1067
 ... 6 rows omitted
```

And Q3 (aggregate sessions that contain multiple products):

```
dt.long[, 
  if(length(items <- .SD[all(c("ProductB") %in% V2), V2])) paste0(items, collapse=", "), 
  by=Session
]
```

Produces (note you don't have any sessions with more than one product shared, but you can easily modify the above for multiple products for your real data):

```
   Session                           V1
1:   31976 ProductB, ProductB, ProductB
2:   25756 ProductC, ProductC, ProductB
```

Q2 is a bit trickier, but I'll leave that one to you.  I'm also not 100% sure what you mean by that question.  One thing worth highlighting, `dt.long` here has the products repeated however many times they were "xed".  For example, with session 27966, product 1069 shows up twice, so you can count rows for each product if you want:

```
> dt.long[Session==27966]
   Session TotSales   V2
1:   27966       25 1069
2:   27966       25 1069
```

Note that the regular expression we use to split products will work so long as you don't have products with names (not codes) like "BLHABLBHA98877x998".

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the `GameList` column. This is probably kind of slow for bigger datasets, but should show the general idea:

```
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

DF <- read.table(text="Session  TotSales    GameList
20764      15        ProductA
31976       7        ProductB:ProductB:ProductB
27966      25        1069x2
324         3        1067x1
6943       28        1071x1:1064x1:1038x2:1034x1:ProductE
14899      12        1062x2
25756       8        ProductC:ProductC:ProductB
27279       6        ProductD:ProductD:ProductD:PcoductC
31981       4        1067x1
2782      529        1046x2:1046x2:1046x1:1046x1:1046x1:1046x4", header=TRUE)

DF <- do.call(rbind,
              lapply(seq_len(nrow(DF)), 
                     function(i) cbind.data.frame(DF[i,-3], 
                                                  Game=strsplit(DF$GameList, ":", fixed=TRUE)[[i]])))

DF <- cbind(DF, 
            t(sapply(strsplit(DF$Game, "x", fixed=TRUE), 
       function(x) {if (length(x)<2L) x <- c(x, 1); x})))
DF <- DF[,-3]

names(DF)[3:4] <- c("Game", "Amount") 

DF$Amount <- as.integer(DF$Amount)
DF$index <- seq_len(nrow(DF))

#    Session TotSales     Game Amount index
# 1    20764       15 ProductA      1     1
# 2    31976        7 ProductB      1     2
# 3    31976        7 ProductB      1     3
# 4    31976        7 ProductB      1     4
# 31   27966       25     1069      2     5
# 41     324        3     1067      1     6
# 7     6943       28     1071      1     7
# 8     6943       28     1064      1     8
# 9     6943       28     1038      2     9
# 10    6943       28     1034      1    10
# 11    6943       28 ProductE      1    11
# 6    14899       12     1062      2    12
# 13   25756        8 ProductC      1    13
# 14   25756        8 ProductC      1    14
# 15   25756        8 ProductB      1    15
# 16   27279        6 ProductD      1    16
# 17   27279        6 ProductD      1    17
# 18   27279        6 ProductD      1    18
# 19   27279        6 PcoductC      1    19
# 91   31981        4     1067      1    20
# 21    2782      529     1046      2    21
# 22    2782      529     1046      2    22
# 23    2782      529     1046      1    23
# 24    2782      529     1046      1    24
# 25    2782      529     1046      1    25
# 26    2782      529     1046      4    26
```

Note that I assume that there is no `x` in the product names. If there is, you need a regex as shown by @BrodieG for splitting.

Now you can do things like this:

```
aggregate(Game~Session, DF, head, 1)
#    Session     Game
# 1      324     1067
# 2     2782     1046
# 3     6943     1071
# 4    14899     1062
# 5    20764 ProductA
# 6    25756 ProductC
# 7    27279 ProductD
# 8    27966     1069
# 9    31976 ProductB
# 10   31981     1067
```

Comment: After in run that first chunk of code , I get this error:

 Error in strsplit(data1$GameList, ":", fixed = T) : 
  non-character argument

Comment: Yes, with the exception of reading the table in, I ran everything from options(...) to the end of "data1<-do.call"

I ran it on the full DF, but I wouldn't think that would make a difference in the code, would it?

Comment: The option ensures that there are no factor columns in your data.frame. The error message indicates that there is a factor column. You need to set the option prior to data import or convert the columns to `character` afterwards.

Comment: Ah, gotcha...I had already imported. Re-imported and it worked great.  Thank you.

Comment: There does seem to be one problem- what are your thoughts on necessary processing time?  The data.frame is 389,000 lines long, and that initial do.call code was still processing after an hour.  Think that is just a function of the long data.frame or is there something else afoot?

Comment: Yes, I expect this code to be slow. As I said already, it would be best to create the data in a better format. You could use other languages for the text processing. And I'm also sure that the R code could be optimized a bit. My code was only intended to show the general strategy. It's not for production use.